# Postgres Sequence reacting different to code and pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, matlab, database-sequence

I am working on a project with Matlab-2017b and PosgreSQL(via ODBC drivers).
In the code there are some files that needed to be renamed with the database table's corresponding id number.

While doing some testing with the scenario where the sequence's current value is 1 test results shows this weird behaviour.

If the pgAdmin-4 Gui is used to open sequence properties and set the current value to 1 after the code executes the sequence returns 2.

[image: Sequence current value altered via pgAdminGui]
[image: The newly inserted element's id is 2]

But if the query below from MATLAB is run:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

then code executed, the newly inserted element id's column is 1.

[image: The newly inserted element's row id after the query executed]

While the code already handled to work properly, there are still some curiosity about what goes on behind this?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and show us the code that shows the "weird behaviour".

Comment: The file goes from a set of validations before renaming then inserted to database. I do not have the values in the table before the renaming step.

Comment: But you can get the sequence value using `currval()` or `lastval()` in your code before actually inserting the data. Resetting a sequence is not something that should be done on a regular basis - only if you remove all rows from the table that uses the sequence

Comment: I already fixed the problematic part with the functions you suggested. Thanks for that.
But what causes the difference when restarting sequence is done from the code and from the pgAdmin?

Comment: That looks fine to me. `RESTART WITH 1;` means that the next call to `nextval()` will return 1  (which is clearly documented in the manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st case (PgAdmin), you have set the **current** value to 1, so the next one that will be fetch will be 2.

In the 2nd case ([restart](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) sequence), you set the **next** value to 1, so the next one that will be fetch will be 1.